# Removing Blank lines between data rows in CLPPlus

Tags: db2, db2-luw, clpplus

Hi I have google this many many times but i cannot seem to find the resolution. The resolutions suggested previoulsy do not seem to work for me.
I am using CLPPlus to query DB2 and when i create the spool file i get a blank row after each data row. 
I have set pagesize to 0, changed the trim settings so no leading whitespace. None of these worked.
Please see the screenshot below for further help
Please see the code below:

```
set echo off
set colsep '|'
set pages 0
set trimspool on
set headsep "|"
set linesize 500
set heading on
set feedback off
set timing off
set recsep off

spool C:\Users\mkhan59\Desktop\CLPPlus\DB2_Result.txt

set termout off
Select Query Here;
set termout on
SPOOL OFF
```

[image: As you can see from Screenshot there are blank lines after each row.]

Comment: I don't get that problem. At the last character of each row is a newline, but not a blank line.  Edit your question to include *what* you tried, in particular whether `set recsep off` has any effect, and also specify the output of the command `db2level` (run this command in a db2cmd.exe window).

Comment: @Mao I have added a screenshot of my result. As you can see that after each line there is a blank row. I need to remove this. I have tried `set pagesize 0` and also changed the settings to remove trailing and leading whitespace. None fixed the issue :(

Comment: Answer the questions re db2level and `set recsp`.

Comment: You seem to be opening the file in Excel or some other spreadsheet application; how do you know it's not the application artifact? Have you tried looking at the output file using a plain text editor, or `type` it from the command line?

Comment: @mustaccio I have looked at in notepad++ and i get the same issue. there is a blank line after each row. @mao what is db2lvl, sorry not aware of that and tried `set recsp` didnt fix the issue